# How to use Evaluate inside function definitions?

Tags: evaluation, hold

How to use Evaluate inside function definition so that is acts as Evaluate only whet function is called?

This is toy exampl, where I want to define function inside another function:

```
Clear[y, x];
f1[a_] := Module[
   {test, testF},
   test = a x + 2;
   testF[x_] := Evaluate[test];
   testF[y]
];
f1[6]
```

I want result  "2 + 6 y", but get "2 + 6 x"

Comment: `Evaluate` is completely unnecessary here -- you could just as well define `test[x_] := a x + 2`. I assume your actual problem is more complicated than this, but your minimal example is not a very good one. Perhaps you should include your actual question, even if more complicated. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346882).

Comment: To be more specific, `Clear[y, x];
f1[a_] := Module[{test, testF}, test = a x + 2;
   Set @@{testF[x_], test};
   testF[y]];
f1[6]` will resolve your problem. Notice `Evaluate` is not relevant here, what's causing trouble is renaming inside `Module`, which has been explained in the post linked above.